# Php foreach - separating each loop with comma except the last element

Tags: php

Heres what i mean:

```
foreach ($array as $a) {
 echo $a.',<br/>';
}
```

current output would be:

```
a,
a,
a,
a,
```

i want the output to be like this:

```
a,
a,
a,
a
```

(all 'a' separated with comma and when it comes to the last loop it doesnt write a comma)

Comment: use `echo implode(",<br />",$array)`

Comment: Do you also want the <br/> but no comma?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo implode(",<br/>", $array);
```

Answer (score 3):

If the length of array is too large or you have multidimensional array use the below code

```
<?php $len=count($array);
    foreach($array as $a){ 
        echo $a; 
        if( $len > 1) echo ','; 
        $len--;
 } ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you'd also like to convert any newlines in the array to `<br />`, which might be ideal if you're outputting:

```
echo nl2br(implode(',' . PHP_EOL, $array));
```

Comment: why the trim() and the nl2br, instead of directly imploding with <br/>?

Comment: `nl2br` because I like it to look nice in the source code as well -- I don't know why I had `trim`. Also, it would convert any new lines in the array, which you might want.

Comment: @MichaelRushton: That does not "look nice" but adds heavy load AND BUGs. If he had line-breaks in the values of $array they are now pretty much converted to <br>s, so your code is not working identical to the original code of the question. (Though I admit you _might_ be right about what he _intended_ to code.)

Comment: I should probably add a note to clarify the assumption I made.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has the [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function for that:

```
 implode(",<br>", $array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Nobody said you can make it this way:

```
foreach($array as $element) { 
    $separator = ($element != end($array)) ? ",<br />" : '';
// or $separator = ($element == end($array)) ? '' : ",<br />";   
    echo $element.$separator;
}
```

I suppose this is going to output exactly what you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `implode` except for one situation.

If the output is huge, and you don't want to keep it in memory before sending to the output (e.g. itemwise processing) then you should do something like:

```
$remain=count($array);
foreach ($array as $a) {
    echo $a;
    if($remain-->0) echo ',';
    echo '<br/>';
}
```