# How to remove comma from last items if name3 and name4 are not available (Laravel 8)?

Tags: laravel-8

```
@foreach($items as $item)
        <p>Names:{{ $item->name1 }}, {{$item->name2 }}, {{$item->name3 }}, {{$item->name4 }}</p>
        
@endforeach
```

result: Names: Mimi, Adam, ,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15692464/php-foreach-separating-each-loop-with-comma-except-the-last-element hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You could use tenary statements if you want to keep your code lean:

```php
@foreach($items as $item)
    <p>Names:{{ $item->name1 }}, {{$item->name2 }}, {{$item->name3 }}{{$item->name3?', ':'' }}{{$item->name4 }}{{$item->name4?'.':'' }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Otherwise a simple `if () else ()` conditioning would achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `$items` is an eloquent model collection, you can simply use `join` to concatenate them:

```php
@foreach($items as $item)
  <p>Names:{{ join(', ', $item->only('name1', 'name2', 'name3')) }}</p>     
@endforeach
```